# How can I know the exact search results of a query in the U.S if I'm not in the U.S?

Tags: google-search, search-results, country-specific, localization

Say I am currently in Japan, but I want to know what is the top 10 pages of "learn Japanese" in the U.S, how can I do?

If I search directly, it's a result for audience in my place. Even if I turn it into English or use `google.com/ncr`, it's still not exactly what people in the U.S sees.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

use VPN like "strong VPN" or "tunnel bear" and then open incognito mode, then type google.com for the USA, google.co.uk for the United Kingdom and so on.
Then search for your keyword

Answer (score 0):

There are several websites that will do this for you. You can start with https://serps.com/tools/rank-checker/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a proxy or vpn? You can just choose an US Server, get an US IP and voilà :)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose search engine location according to search required in the USA. Your search engine provides the facility to search in the USA what type of query search related to the USA about your Chinese term.